# How to join two dataframes on 1 column in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

Here are two dataframes :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'product_id': [65, 19, 7, 49, 66, 100],
                  'a': [4, 43, 16, 86, 90, 867],
                  'web_id': [6, 4, 69, 54, '', '']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'web_id': [4, 54, '', ''],
                  'b': [94, 36, 90, 5],
                  'c': [67, 98, 555, '']})
```

The goal is to join df1 and df2 on 'web_id' to get this result :

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'product_id': [65, 19, 7, 49, 66, 100],
                      'a': [4, 43, 16, 86, 90, 867],
                      'web_id': [6, 4, 69, 54, '', ''],
                      'b': [94, 36, 90, 5, '', ''],
                      'c': [67, 98, 555, '', '', '')})
```

Maybe you can help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on axis=1, but first [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas-dataframe-drop) the shared column and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex) to scale `df2` with `''` as the `fill_value`:

```
df3 = pd.concat([
    df1,
    df2.drop('web_id', axis=1).reindex(df1.index, fill_value='')
], axis=1)
```

`df3`:

```
   product_id    a web_id   b    c
0          65    4      6  94   67
1          19   43      4  36   98
2           7   16     69  90  555
3          49   86     54   5     
4          66   90                
5         100  867
```

---

The alternative is to `concat` then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas-dataframe-fillna) however the `dtype`s may convert with the temporary introduction of `NaN`:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2.drop('web_id', axis=1)], axis=1).fillna('')
```

`df3`:

**Notice column b**

```
   product_id    a web_id     b    c
0          65    4      6  94.0   67
1          19   43      4  36.0   98
2           7   16     69  90.0  555
3          49   86     54   5.0     
4          66   90                  
5         100  867
```